# mysql left join echos last row

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table `classifieds` and `state`.

classifieds - `id, title, state_id`

state - `id, statename`

I am trying to echo out the statename from state. I've tried this query but it echos only the last row.

```
    <?php
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM classifieds ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_query());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
   ?>

    <div>
   <span>Title: <?php echo $row['title'];?> </span>
    </div>

   <div>
   <span>Name: <?php echo $row['name'];?> </span>
    </div>

      $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classifieds AS C
    LEFT JOIN  state AS S
    ON C.state_id = S.id");
    $z = array();

    while($state=mysql_fetch_array($q))
     {
      array_push($z,$state["statename"]);
     }

     ?>
    <div>
    <span>State: <?php foreach($z as $location) { echo $location; } ?></span>

    </div>

  <?php } // End of the first while loop ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your `echo` command inside the `while` loop. Otherwise it will only echo once it has gone through all of the rows.

```
 <?php
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classifieds AS C
LEFT JOIN  state AS S
ON C.state_id = S.state_id");
 while($state=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo "Location: ".$state["statename"];
 }
 ?>
```

**Edit:** With your updated code, I can see that your problem is that you first get a list of all the `classifieds`, then that same list again with the states joined in. You don't need to do the first query at all, only the second one.

```
 <?php
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT C.*, S.statename 
       FROM classifieds AS C
       LEFT JOIN  state AS S
       ON C.state_id = S.state_id");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo "Title: ".$row["title"]."<br />";
    echo "Name: ".$row["name"]."<br />";
    echo "Location: ".$state["statename"]."<br />";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Still echos all the states. I updated my code above the way it is.

Comment: @Rocks: Okay, now I think I see what you want to achieve. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwrting the value of `$z` on each loop iteration. If it will have multiple results from the database you'll want to make $z an array as well, and then use array_push() to append the value of $state["statename"] to $z

```
<?php
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classifieds AS C
    LEFT JOIN  state AS S
    ON C.state_id = S.state_id");

$z = array();

while($state=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    array_push($z,$state["statename"]);
}
?>
```

Then use this after your loop to inspect your array...

```
<?php print_r($z); ?>
```

...and this to loop over the array and perform the formatting you require

```
<?php
foreach($z as $location) {
    echo 'Location ' . $location . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Now the result prints like this Location: Array ( [0] => Texas [1] => Arizona [2] => Minnesota )

Comment: Ah yes, I've updated the answer. This is useful if you don't have both portions of your code in the same file. This is typically how you structure MVC projects, or use HTML templates, where the database interaction is not on the same `php` page as your display logic.

Comment: my code is all in one file. I've updated the code the way I have it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the echo statement inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
     $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classifieds AS C LEFT JOIN  state AS S ON C.state_id = S.state_id");

      while($state=mysql_fetch_array($q))
      {
           $z =$state["statename"];
           echo "Location: " . $z . PHP_EOL;
      }
 ?>
```

In your original code, the echo statement outside the loop will only be executed once, i.e. only the last time `$z` was assigned will be displayed. Placing it inside the loop ensures that it will be executed for each of the rows of data.